# Taking part of a zipped archive name and appending it to the files within it

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I need some help! 
I use 7 zip to extract some zipped archives using a batch file. 
Basically what happens is,
some customers transfer some zipped daily archives to an FTP folder,
we then run a batch file which extracts the archives into another folder where Qlik then processes the files.

The problem is, one of the customers have changed the format of the file names (and they are saying they cant change it back!).
Previosuly the file names were in the following format..

```
XXXXXXX_01012018.txt
```

now the names are just

```
XXXXXXX.txt
```

so the date is now missing from the filename.

Unfortunately, this now causes a problem because usually the customer transfers multiple archives at the same time (so for example they will transfer 7 days worth instead of doing it daily),
this means that **when the files are extracted into the Qlik directory structure**,
the 2nd archive will overwrite the first, the 3rd will overwrite the 2nd etc, because the file names will be identical.

I need a way of appending the date to the files in the archive. The date is already in the archive folder name, so i need to take the date from the archive name and append it to the filenames within the archive.

Does anyone know how i can get this done please?
below id my current batch file

```
for /R C:\FTP_FOLDER\Cust1\ %%f in (*.txt) do move "%%f" 
C:\FTP_FOLDER\Cust1\



@echo off

rem | Extract and Archive Telco Operators Files
rem | ==========================================
rem | rem | Version Control
rem | ==========================================
rem | August17 | Initial Version

rem | Set all of the following environment variables
rem | ==========================================
rem **Set 7-Zip Installation Var**
set zip="C:\7-Zip\"
rem **Set Cust1 Environment Vars**
set atFTP=C:\FTP_FOLDER\Cust1\
set atArc=C:\QlikView\SourceData\Cust1\Archive\
set atData=C:\QlikView\SourceData\Cust1\

rem | ==========================================


"%zip%"7z.exe e "%atFTP%BSC*.zip" -aoa -o"%atData%" -r

Move /Y C:\FTP_FOLDER\Cust1\*.zip C:\QlikView\SourceData\Cust1\Archive\

move /Y "%atFTP%*.*" "%atData%"


exit
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is not on topic at StackOverflow, on this site you post the script which is supposed to perform the task but doesn't; we will then try to help you to get it working. Currently as written your question is a script request, now I'm sure that you understand, as as an employee, that you don't work for a Company for free, so why should we? We are happy to help out, but this isn't an all take and no give scenario, make an attempt at the script, and return here with an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50813582/edit) if it fails to work as intended.

Comment: I think your problem is unzip with 7z and a wildcard `"%zip%"7z.exe e "%atFTP%BSC*.zip" -aoa -o"%atData%" -r` you should use a for loop to unzip one after the other and check in between if there are files to append a datestamp to. As long your question lacks details on this it is likely to be put on hold. Also read what a [mcve] is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using qlikview for reporting why dont you add this **filename changing process** in Qlikview right at the start?

So for example when Qlikview starts it will take the txt file from the folder, then export it as txt again with a date, and finally load the information to the application.

At the end delete the txt file without the date.

So whole process in Qlikview. It is way easier like this and you have more control of the file management.